# How to get end date from start date and leave days based on condition using jQuery datapicker

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using JQuery-ui datepicker in Laravel-5.8 for Leave Management Project.

[image: leave days]

I have these models:

HrLeaveRequest

```
class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';

  protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'company_id',
              'employee_id',
              'leave_type_id',
              'leave_day',
              'start_date',
              'end_date',
          ];    

  protected $dates = [
      'start_date',
      'end_date',
  ];

}
```

HrNationalHoliday

```
class HrNationalHoliday extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_national_holidays';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'holiday_name',
                  'holiday_date',
              ];

    protected $dates = [
        'holiday_date'
    ];

}
```

Controller

```
    public function findNationalHoliday(Request $request)
    {
       $nationalholidays               = HrNationalHoliday::select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
     return response()->json([
        'nationalholidays' => $nationalholidays,
     ]);        
   }
```

View

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Start Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                </div>                        
                    <input type="text" id="start_date" class="form-control start_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="start_date" value="{{old('start_date')}}" >
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>                                                
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Days:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input  type="text" 
                id="leave_days" 
                name="leave_days" 
                class="form-control leave_days" 
                placeholder="e.g. 10" 
                value="{{old('leave_days')}}" 
                oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
                style="width: 100%;" 
                maxlength="3" onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)" onkeypress="allowNumbersOnly(event)">
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>End Date:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                </div>                        
                    <input type="text" id="end_date" class="form-control end_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="end_date" value="{{old('end_date')}}" >
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Javascript

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
                var air_id =  $(this).val();
                var a = $(this).parent();
                var op = "";
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '{{ route('get.nationalholidays.all') }}',
                    data: { 'id': air_id },
                    dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#nationalholidays').val(data.nationalholidays);
                        console.log(data.nationalholidays);
                    },
                    error:function(){

                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#leave_days").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
            var periodval=parseInt($("#leave_days").val());

            var startDate = $('.start_date');
            var endDate = $('.end_date');

            var dte = startDate.datepicker("getDate"); 
                    dte.setDate(dte.getDate()+periodval); 
                    endDate.datepicker("setDate", dte);            

          });

            $( '.start_date' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,      
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',   
                minDate: +1,
                setDate: new Date(),
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        }).datepicker('setDate', '1');

            $( '.end_date' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,      
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',   
                minDate: +1,
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
                enableOnReadonly: true,
                beforeShow: function(i) { if ($(i).attr('readonly')) { return false; } }
             });
        });
     </script>
```

Basically, I have a table for NationalHoliday which stores all the national_holidays.

What I want to achieve is that, the user selects the start_date, and as he enters leave_days onchange, it should add national_holidays  (if any) automatically  display end_date. Note that the end_date is disabled.

So far, when the users enters leave_days automatically displays end_date, but not removing NationalHolidays.

I have this in my console:

[image: national holidays]

How do I :

1. Consume the NationalHolidays from JSON in the controller into the view (also remove the time its bringing along with the date) ? It is in date format and I've been trying to do this:
   $('#nationalholidays').val(data.nationalholidays);
   which is not working and there's nothing like #nationalholidays
2. How do I add the national holidays to the leave_days to get the end_date?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot find any console.log. So where does the console output come from?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - It is there:     console.log(data.nationalholidays);

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to JSON.parse() the result from your AJAX Query and store it in a variable.
Then you can create a loop adding day by day and only decrease the leave days if the actual day is not in the array of the holidays you requested.

Comment: Can you give me an example